# Div not centered and footer moves up

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I would like the div (home) to be in the middle of the page. The problem with me is that when I shrink the browser window at the bottom, the footer moves up with it and then eventually disappears underneath. And should I reduce the page in the browser, so zoom out, then you can see that the logo and the text are not in the middle.

I can't get the footer to stay at the bottom and the logo and text to be in the middle of the page.

I use Bootstrap 5

CODE: https://jsfiddle.net/esznkh4r/3/

VIDEO: https://i.imgur.com/XRAX2bq.mp4

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.home {
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.logo {
  height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="home">
            <div class="container">
                <img class="logo d-block mx-auto mb-4" src="https://duckduckgo.com/assets/common/dax-logo.svg" alt="LOGO">
                <div class="text">
                    <h1>TEST</h1>
                    <h6>BLABLABLABLABLA</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div class="container d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center py-3">

            <div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                <span>TEST</span>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav col-md-4 justify-content-end d-flex">
                <a class="mb-0 justify-content-end" target="_blank">TEST</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: What do you mean by ```shrink the browser window at the bottom```? Usually developers test responsiveness of a website by changing the width of window not the height. If you want to check that the footer **stays at the bottom** you must remove the logo. Then if the footer is still in its previous position, it means that it stays at the bottom.

Comment: Above is a clip, maybe that clarifies more my problem

Comment: what you did is a bit strange and unclear for me. Could you explain that **why** you shrink the browser window at the bottom? I think if you do that action in any other website the same things happen and the elements that are near the bottom disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

Set `flex` property into `.wrapper`.

[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/fuo2qbry/13/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, remove `.home` class style, and add

```
.wrapper {
   flex: 1;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added some property in `.home` class

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.home {
  padding: 150px 0;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo {
  height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="home">
            <div class="container">
                <img class="logo d-block mx-auto mb-4" src="https://duckduckgo.com/assets/common/dax-logo.svg" alt="LOGO">
                <div class="text">
                    <h1>TEST</h1>
                    <h6>BLABLABLABLABLA</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div class="container d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center py-3">

            <div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                <span>TEST</span>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav col-md-4 justify-content-end d-flex">
                <a class="mb-0 justify-content-end" target="_blank">TEST</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
```